# Como faço pra calcular tamanho dos Widgets para diferentes resoluções?

Tags: flutter

Por exemplo, tenho o seguinte `SizedBox`:

```
SizedBox(
  width: 40,
  height: 40
)
```

O valor 40 é um tamanho fixo definido pelo protótipo na resolução baseline (1x).
Quero que esses valores sejam atualizados pra quando eu mudar pra diferentes resoluções (0.75x, 2x, 3x, 4x...).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode utilizar um helper para ajudar a escalar um tamanho fixo de acordo com a resolução da tela em que você estiver rodando a sua aplicação.

Em Flutter a gente consegue identificar o tamanho da tela atual através do [MediaQuery](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html) como:

```dart
MediaQuery.of(context).size.width // imprime o tamanho da largura da tela
MediaQuery.of(context).size.height // imprime o tamanho da altura da tela
```

Com base nesse tamanho podemos fazer algum cálculo similar a:

1. Tamanho padrão = **40**

   - Se a largura da tela for maior que **600**, é um tablet! -> 40 * 2 = **60**
   - Se a largura da tela for maior que **320**, é uma tela pequena! -> 40 * 0.8 = **32**

> 600 pois os tablets começam a partir desta resolução, e 320 pois as telas menores (iphone 4s e 5s) possuem esse tamanho de largura.

Acontece que dependendo do modo que estivermos usando o app (PORTRAIT/LANDSCAPE) a largura e altura são invertidas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então para evitar esse problema, podemos pegar sempre o menor dos lados para a validação, com o:

```dart
MediaQuery.of(context).size.shortestSide
```

Com base nisso podemos criar esse helper:

```dart
class SizeConfig {

  final MediaQueryData mediaQueryData;

  SizeConfig({this.mediaQueryData});

  static SizeConfig of(BuildContext context) =>
      SizeConfig(mediaQueryData: MediaQuery.of(context));

  double dynamicScaleSize({double size, double scaleFactorTablet, double scaleFactorMini}) {
    if(isTablet()) {
      final scaleFactor = scaleFactorTablet ?? 2;
      return size * scaleFactor;
    }

    if(isMini()) {
      final scaleFactor = scaleFactorMini ?? 0.8;
      return size * scaleFactor;
    }

    return size;
  }

  /// Defines device type based on logical device pixels. Bigger than 600 means it is a tablet
  bool isTablet() {
    final shortestSide = mediaQueryData.size.shortestSide;
    return shortestSide > 600;
  }

  /// Defines device type based on logical device pixels. Less or equal than 320 means it is a mini device
  bool isMini() {
    final shortestSide = mediaQueryData.size.shortestSide;
    return shortestSide <= 320;
  }
}
```

O `SizeConfig` acima mantém por padrão um fator de multiplicação de 2 para tablets e 0.8 para mini, valores baseados em minha experiência própria de utilização. Também é possível passar um valor customizado, dependendo da utilização.

Se houver a necessidade de incluir outros tamanhos de tela essa mesma classe pode ser alterada, mas até o momento não encontrei essa necessidade.

É possível inicializá-lo com o construtor, ou utilizar diretamente com o `of()`:

```dart
final sizeConfig = SizeConfig(mediaQueryData: MediaQuery.of(context));
SizeConfig.of(context);
```

Na prática:

```dart
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[SizeWidget()],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SizeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final sizeConfig = SizeConfig(mediaQueryData: MediaQuery.of(context));

    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              width: sizeConfig.dynamicScaleSize(size: 50),
              height: sizeConfig.dynamicScaleSize(size: 50),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: sizeConfig.dynamicScaleSize(size: 40, scaleFactorTablet: 3.5),
              width: sizeConfig.dynamicScaleSize(size: 40, scaleFactorTablet: 2),
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              'Tamanho do Texto',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: SizeConfig.of(context).dynamicScaleSize(size: 20, scaleFactorTablet: 2)),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Resultado em um celular 'normal':

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No tablet sem o fator de escala e com fator de escala:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o/